# ¿Existe algún hosting gratuito en ASP.net y C# para hospedar sitio Web personal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

¿Existe algún hosting gratuito en ASP.net, C# y SQL Server para hospedar sitio Web personal?

Comment: Azure es una buena opcion, pero no incluye Sql Server free. Es mas no creo que ningun sitio gratuito incluya Sql Server

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque este no es un sitio de recomendaciones

Comment: El problema de ASP.NET es el tema de la licencia que debes de pagar por tu Windows Server, tu SQL Server por esa razon, practicamente nadie da gratis ese servicio y quien lo llega a dar, es basura

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si, yo tengo tres sitios en azurewebsites:

```
http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/
http://bigsurgarrapata.azurewebsites.net/
http://usamaporama.azurewebsites.net/
```

Nunca he pagado por ellos.

Puedes mirar en [How Azure pricing works](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/)

Comment: es muy buen servicio, lo unico malo es que necesitas tarjeta de crédito

Comment: Creo que hoy en día la gran mayoría pide tarjeta de crédito @B. Clay Shannon , evaluaste otros sitios para trabajar con C#.Net y y base de datos?

Comment: @Elenasys: Si, pero los otros son mas dificil de manejar, y tambien cuesta dinero! Soy un poco alergico con cosas asi. Disculpeme por mi espanol mala.

Comment: +1 Recomendado Azure! ([tiene sus limites la version free que tenes que evaluar](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/pricing/details/app-service/plans/)) Como te comenta te piden tarjeta de credito solo para validar

Comment: Si no necesita C#/.NET, una otra posibilidad es Meteor con MongoDB y Atom - completamente gratis!

Comment: @rnrneverdies , yo tengo mi azure con tarjeta visa débito acá en Perú y no tengo problemas, ahora sql server en azure no es gratis lamentablemente, y hasta donde recuerdo solo te permiten una instancia gratuita o de pago(?) de mysql.

Comment: casi nada es gratis, lamentablemente no tienen planes para proyectos open source ni personales.

Comment: y "gratis" es casi nada realmente "gratis" - siempre quiere algo.

Comment: Estoy buscando un hosting como `www.000webhost.com`, actualmente para **PHP**, pero en este caso para **ASP.Net** y que te ofrezca la opción de usar **tu propio nombre de dominio**.

Comment: Creo que eso es posible en azure, pero para tu propio nombre de dominio, debes pagar algo (no se, cuantos).

Answer (score 2):

Creo que depende de varios aspectos por ejemplo que tanta capacidad de almacenaje requieres y el ancho de banda, personalmente para proyectos pequeños uso `http://www.tripod.lycos.com/`

Existen algunos como:

```
http://www.wix.com/
https://byet.host/
http://www.weebly.com/
```

Estrictamente para C#.Net yo usaría Azure:

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/
```

y si, la gran mayoría pide tarjeta de crédito...